# How to save selected worksheets as a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to write a macro to select certain worksheets into a new file.

the tricky part is that I want to save all worksheets but 3.

I've managed to select the worksheets but I can't find how to create a new workbook and then save it.

here's my code, the sub stops at  `Sheets(Array(Selection)).Copy`

which is not the correct command.

thanks for you help

```
Sub ExportPrices()

Dim ExportName As String
Dim ReportingDir As String
Dim Dashboard As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dashboard = ThisWorkbook.Name
ExportName = Workbooks(Dashboard).Worksheets("Macro").Range("ExportName").Value
ReportingDir = Workbooks(Dashboard).Worksheets("Macro").Range("ReportingDir").Value


Workbooks(Dashboard).Worksheets("Europe").Select

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Macro" And ws.Name <> "Dashboard" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then
ws.Select (False)
    End If
Next

'create an array from selection

Sheets(Array(Selection)).Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ReportingDir & ExportName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add new workbook and copy target sheet to wb:

```
 Dim oOutBook As Workbook
 Set oOutBook = Workbooks.Add
 Sheets(Array(Selection)).Copy Before:=oOutBook.Sheets(1)
 oOutBook.SaveAs strPathOutput
```

Comment: I still get an Run-time error '9' on the line

`Sheets(Array(Selection)).Copy`

when this happens all the sheets I want to copy to the new file are selected, but I don't know how to refer to this selection with the code.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.Move` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.move) in VBA. When not presented with a location to move to, the `.Move` method will move the specified sheet into a new workbook.

```
Sheets("Yoursheet").Move
```

As this will always be the latest created workbook, you can then refer to this by using `Workbooks.Count`:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
```

Comment: The point is that I don't want to name the sheets.
The number of sheet to export will grow in the future and I'd like to keep the code flexible to copy everything but the worksheet "Macro" "dashboard" "data"